# array_push cambia los valores

Tags: php, array, object

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9591400c9ae565679ce774e91c43d140d6daa53f

Como pueden ver en el ejemplo `array_push` o `array_unshift` guarda [data] con el último valor.

```
<?php
$filters   = json_decode(strtolower('{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"codigo","op":"cn","data":"ampolla 213"},{"field":"codigo","op":"cn","data":"hola rzD"}]}'));
        if (count(explode(' ', preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $filters->rules[0]->data)))>1) {
            $tmp_array = $filters->rules[0];
            array_shift($filters->rules);

            unset($tmp_array->data);
            foreach(explode(' ', preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $filters->rules[0]->data)) as &$value) {
                $tmp_array->data = $value;
                print_r($tmp_array);
                array_unshift($filters->rules, $tmp_array);
            }
            print_r($filters);
        }
```

Output

```
stdClass Object
(
    [field] => codigo
    [op] => cn
    [data] => hola
)
stdClass Object
(
    [field] => codigo
    [op] => cn
    [data] => rzd
)
stdClass Object
(
    [groupop] => and
    [rules] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [field] => codigo
                    [op] => cn
                    [data] => rzd
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [field] => codigo
                    [op] => cn
                    [data] => rzd
                )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando cambias el valor de `$tmp_array->data` estás afectando a todas las ocurrencias de ese objeto `stdClass` contenidas en el array `$filters->rules`, porque ese objeto que insertas ("prependeas") en el array con `array_unshift` pasa **por referencia**.

Esto consta en la [documentación](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php):

> As of PHP 5, an object variable doesn't contain the object itself as
>   value anymore. It only contains an object identifier which allows
>   object accessors to find the actual object. When an object is sent by
>   argument, returned or assigned to another variable, the different
>   variables are not aliases: they hold a copy of the identifier, which
>   **points to the same object**.

Esto lo podrías probar con un ejemplo más simple:

```
<?php

$rules=[];
$objeto=new stdClass();

$objeto->data='valor 0';
$rules[] = $objeto;

$objeto->data='valor 1';
$rules[] = $objeto;

$objeto->data='valor 2';
$rules[] = $objeto;

print_r($rules);
```

(Puedes verlo en http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8ac2f4f0b54365be3f3521e3efcdf6a13bafb34a)

Si quisieras modificar el valor insertado en cada bucle, tendrías que crear un nuevo objeto o clonar el anterior:

```
<?php

$rules=[];
$objeto=new stdClass();

$objeto->data='valor 0';
$rules[] = $objeto;

$objeto = clone $objeto;
$objeto->data='valor 1';
$rules[] = $objeto;

$objeto = clone $objeto;
$objeto->data='valor 2';
$rules[] = $objeto;

print_r($rules);
```

(Ver en http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fc0d55b7adea8b05bb02be8c947207ceddf6f337)

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por tu comentario, estuve investigando mucho antes de preguntar (lo tuve que pasar con  json_enconde( , TRUE) y no tuve estos inconvenientes.

Saludos.